# Excel: How to color cells based on color of other cells having same value in a range?

Tags: vba, excel, validation, conditional-formatting

I have a range / table of say 10 rows to 3 columns.

Any particular cell can have any particular value from the list created using Data validation. All the cells in this range have the same data validation list.

If a value repeats across any row or across any column, not diagonally or otherwise, then those values are highlighted using conditional formatting.

Now I want that if the same value is present elsewhere in non-duplicate row or column, then those cells should be colored too. (Preferably a different color than one used for conditional formatting to know the difference between both).

The purpose is to know which values are repeated and how, and where in the range those values are used but are not repeated as per the criteria.

P.s.: Please tell if additional information or some clarification is required.

Refer the attached image to understand my query better.
The blue ones are colored through conditional formatting and the green ones are needed to be colored through your help.

[Image for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wpll.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional formatting->Duplicate Values for the whole range, with different color and set up sequence in Conditional Formatting->Manage Rules. No need of VBA in my opinion.

EDIT:
Ok, I think I know what are you asking for. Try this little subroutine:

```
Sub PaintDuplis()
Dim rng As Range
Dim col As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cl As Range, cl2 As Range

Set rng = Range("B4:D11") 'or whatever your range is.
'Columns
For Each col In rng.Columns
  For Each cl In col.Cells
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(col, cl.Value) > 1 Then cl.Interior.Color =    vbYellow
  Next cl
Next col

'Rows
For Each row In rng.rows
  For Each cl In row.Cells
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(row, cl.Value) > 1 Then cl.Interior.Color = vbYellow
  Next cl
Next row

'Paint whole range
For Each cl In rng
  If cl.Interior.Color = vbYellow Then
    For Each cl2 In rng
        If cl2.Value = cl.Value And cl2.Interior.Color <> vbYellow Then cl2.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Next cl2
  End If
Next cl
```

I have given up conditional formatting, instead I have used VBA to paint duplicates in columns/rows and then painted all still white cells with red if it equals to one already in yellow. Hope it helped.

Comment: No, actually, the whole range duplicates are not needed to be highlighted. Whole range will have duplicates as each column will have same data set.

Color highlight is needed only when the data repeats across one row or one column.

Comment: So you need conditional formatting for each column and for each row separately.. If there is large number of rows, you could use macro to format them one by one.

Comment: No. I already have conditional formatting for each row and each column separately.
Now what I need is to highlight those cells in the range which have same value as is marked duplicate by the conditional formatting, other than those marked as duplicate.

Comment: So you need just one of the two (or more) duplicated values to be highlighted, not all of them - is this correct?

Comment: No. Say column one has duplicate values in row 3 and 8. So cells (3,1) and (8,1) will be highlighted using conditional formatting rule.
Now, the duplicate value be (say) "X". X is also observed in cells (4,2) and (7,3). I need to highlight these cells also.

But similarly, in the whole range, value "Z" is present in cells (1,1), (5,2) and (10,3). So that is not duplicate in any row or any column. So these should not be colored, although they are duplicate across the whole range.

Comment: Does this pseudocode illustrate your goal:
`For Each cell In conditionalFormattingHighlightedCells For Each otherCell In allCells If cell = otherCell Then otherCell.Style = "Highlighted" Next otherCell Next cell` ?

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec Hey thanks! But I need your help in following things:
1. How to input my own colors in this code?
2. I want this to work as soon as someone enters values in the range. How to call the sub real time as someone changes a value in the range?
3. As soon as the user changes the duplicate value to non-duplicate, the colors should again be removed. Your solution is not handling this right now. How to do that?

I think this is why I need duplicate check instead of count check. That as soon as duplicates are removed, the color highlights are removed.

Comment: come on, you can easily google it. Add 2&3: use events for this worksheet.

Comment: @MarcinSzaleniec I am not able to remove the highiighted color when the duplicates are removed. How to do that?

Comment: @MaciejLipinski Yes that illustrates my goal. Just that once the conditional formatting highlight is removed (say duplicate value is deleted), then the other cell highlight should be automatically removed.

Comment: That's not possible without 1. removing the macro-induced formatting and 2. running the entire macro again. This could be resource-intensive and annoying, if every cell edit by the user is followed by several seconds (optimistically) of macro busytime. You could have the macro run on the BeforeSave event, thus validating the formatting.

Comment: @MaciejLipinski To clarify, forget about my problem and see it as a Sudoku game. In standard Sudoku games, the cells with duplicate value in box, row or column are highlighted and as soon as the duplicate are removed the color is removed. Similarly all other cells with value that is selected are highlighted with a color. That's exactly what I need in my excel, just that here it is not a game.